# Why can't an angle-based crosshair, measure travel distance at all distances to target?

Tags: trigonometry

[This Reddit post](https://redd.it/4l2ecz) argues: Basic trigonometry implies that angle-based crosshairs [henceforth ABC], can't measure travel distance, at all distances to target.

I might have missed something: why do you need trigonometry to understand the above? To what trigonometry does the above refer?

Isn't the explanation that any reticle (e.g. pictures 2 and 3 below) must be defined and so be referring to a specific distance (e.g. 100 yards from the gun)? Or have I neglected some facts?  Picture 1 implies that different distances to target does not affect the angle.

[image]

Comment: OK, after poking around a couple of World of Warships sites, my tentative conclusion is the point of confusion is that people use the wrong words to describe how targeting works. Notice that the 1 MOA angle measures 3 times as much lateral distance at 300 yards as at 100 yards. That's why the Reddit post argued it doesn't measure travel distance. Thing is, knowing travel distance alone is not what lets you hit a moving target.

Comment: The really laughable thing is that battleships of that era carried sophisticated mechanical computers receiving data from sophisticated spotting and rangefinding equipment. The kind of guesswork that people in that game are forced to perform was not necessary in real life.

Comment: @DavidK +1. I upvoted your comments above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the direct question, no, you don't need to use any sines, cosines, or other things generally taught as "trigonometry" in order to state that the angular separation between two locations, seen from a particular viewpoint, does not by itself predict the distance between those locations,
even when we require that both locations be the same distance from the viewer.
It's sufficient to use principles of similar triangles, which math educators generally teach under the topic of "plane geometry" before introducing anything they call "trigonometry".

In the broader sense, however, trigonometry in general is the study of the relationships between angles and the lengths of sides of triangles that have those angles. So in a sense, as soon as we think of the reticle as measuring an angle, we introduce some concepts of trigonometry, even if we never mention (let alone look up or calculate) the sine, tangent, or any other "trigonometric" function of that angle.

The argument in the Reddit post appears to be mistaken in its main point, however. If you view two warships both steaming at a speed of $20$ knots perpendicularly to your line of sight, one $1000$ meters away from you and the other $2000$ meters away from you, the farther warship will have to steam twice as far (taking twice as much time) to reach the point in its path aligned with the fifth tick mark of the horizontal reticle.
But that point is twice as far from you as the corresponding point in the path of the nearer ship, and the shells from your guns will take longer to get there.
Neglecting air resistance and the difference of the cosines of the elevation angles required to hit targets at those locations, the shells will take twice as long to reach the farther target, so to hit the farther ship you would need to aim at a location twice as far in front of that ship.
By similar triangles, this occurs at the same reticle angle as the one that gives the correct "lead" for the closer ship.

If we *do* take air resistance and elevation angle into account, it turns out that the average horizontal velocity of the shell fired at the farther target is lower than that of the shell fired at the closer target, so we would have to increase the angle of lead for the farther target.
(I don't know if either of these effects is taken into account in the game that is discussed by the Reddit user, but these effects occurred in real life.)
But these are second-order effects related to the properties of shells fired from guns, not related to anything about the geometry of the reticle, the speeds of the warships, or the distances traveled by the warships.

Ironically, for ships moving at the same speed, these effects produce a *greater* lead angle in the reticle for ships that are farther away,
whereas if we wanted to use the reticle to estimate equal distances along the paths of the ships (or where the ships will both be at the same time in the future), we would use a *smaller* angle in the reticle for the farther ship.
So the complaint about the "trigonometry" of the reticle seems to advocate for a "correction" that is opposite from the one that would be needed.